# AD FAILED {"code": 0, "domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads", "message": "Internal error."} React native react-native-admob-native-ads

Tags: react-native, ads

I'm having problems with react-native-admob-native-ads. I code the ads part and I've tried all types of inter, resum, and banner ads, but the native ads have the problem: AD FAILED {"code": 0, "domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads", "message": "Internal error."} I have tried a few ways but the problem doesn't seem to be solved. My code is based on the example of react-native-admob-native-ads
this is my code:

```
     import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import NativeAdView, {
  CallToActionView,
  HeadlineView,
  IconView,
  NativeMediaView,
  TaglineView,
} from 'react-native-admob-native-ads';
import Config from 'react-native-config';

import ShimmerPlaceholder from '~/screens/components/ShimmerPlaceholder';

const NativeAdsOnboarding1 = React.memo(
  ({ onPress }: { onPress: (arg: boolean) => void }): JSX.Element => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const nativeAdRef = useRef<NativeAdView>(null);
    const ID_Native =
      (Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? Config?.ANDROID_NATIVE_LANGUAGE
        : Config?.IOS_NATIVE_LANGUAGE) || '';
    useEffect(() => {
      nativeAdRef.current?.loadAd();
    }, []);
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   setTimeout(() => {
    //     if (error) {
    //       setError(false);
    //       console.log('111');
    //       nativeAdRef.current?.loadAd();
    //     }
    //   }, 5000);
    // }, [error]);
    const onAdFailedToLoad = (event: any) => {
      setError(true);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log('AD', 'FAILED', event);
      onPress(false);
    };
    const onAdLoaded = async () => {
      console.log('AD', 'LOADED', 'Ad has loaded successfully');
      await analytics().logEvent('onboarding1_ad_native_view');
      onPress(true);
    };
    const onAdClicked = async () => {
      await analytics().logEvent('onboarding1_ad_native_click');
      console.log('AD', 'CLICK', 'User has clicked the Ad');
    };
    const onAdImpression = () => {
      console.log('AD', 'IMPRESSION', 'Ad impression recorded');
    };
    const onNativeAdLoaded = (event: any) => {
      console.log('AD', 'RECIEVED', 'Unified ad  Recieved', event);
      setLoading(false);
      setLoaded(true);
      setError(false);
    };
    const onAdLeftApplication = () => {
      console.log('AD', 'LEFT', 'Ad left application');
    };
    return (
      <NativeAdView
        adUnitID={ID_Native}
        ref={nativeAdRef}
        onAdLoaded={onAdLoaded}
        onAdFailedToLoad={onAdFailedToLoad}
        onAdLeftApplication={onAdLeftApplication}
        onAdClicked={onAdClicked}
        onAdImpression={onAdImpression}
        onNativeAdLoaded={onNativeAdLoaded}
        refreshInterval={60000}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
        }}
        videoOptions={{
          customControlsRequested: true,
        }}
        mediationOptions={{
          nativeBanner: true,
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 270 : 250,
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 12,
            borderTopRightRadius: 12,
            paddingTop: 8,
            backgroundColor: '#D4D7D8',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              position: 'absolute',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              opacity: !loading && !error && loaded ? 0 : 1,
              zIndex: !loading && !error && loaded ? 0 : 10,
            }}>
            {!loading && (
              <ShimmerPlaceholder
                width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                height={258}
                style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 12, borderTopRightRadius: 12 }}
              />
            )}
            {error && <Text style={{ color: '#a9a9a9' }}>:-(</Text>}
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              marginVertical: 8,
              opacity: loading || error || !loaded ? 0 : 1,
            }}>
            <IconView
              style={{
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
              }}
            />
            <View
              style={{
                paddingHorizontal: 8,
                flexShrink: 1,
                maxWidth: '90%',
              }}>
              <HeadlineView
                numberOfLines={1}
                ellipsizeMode='tail'
                style={{
                  fontWeight: '700',
                  color: '#000',
                  marginBottom: 4,
                  fontSize: 12,
                }}
              />
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#12B7EB',
                    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                    marginRight: 8,
                    marginTop: 4,
                  }}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#FFF',
                      fontSize: 8,
                      fontWeight: '600',
                      paddingHorizontal: 4,
                      paddingVertical: 2,
                    }}>
                    AD
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <TaglineView
                  numberOfLines={2}
                  ellipsizeMode='tail'
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: '500',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    color: '#000',
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <NativeMediaView
            style={{
              width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 40,
              height: 120,
              borderRadius: 8,
              marginBottom: 8,
              // backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}
            // resizeMode='cover'
          />
          <CallToActionView
            style={[
              {
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                elevation: 10,
                height: 44,
                width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 40,
                // marginBottom: 20,
                // marginTop: 8,
              },
              Platform.OS === 'ios'
                ? {
                    backgroundColor: '#1562EC',
                    borderRadius: 40,
                  }
                : {},
            ]}
            buttonAndroidStyle={{
              backgroundColor: '#1562EC',
              borderRadius: 40,
            }}
            allCaps
            textStyle={{
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: '500',
              flexWrap: 'wrap',
              textAlign: 'center',
              // marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 24,
              color: 'white',
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </NativeAdView>
    );
  },
);
export default NativeAdsOnboarding1;
```